# Changing form in VS2010 c# From Designer doesn't change the form when i run it

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

This is probably a real beginners question, so i hope it is appropriate. I have a sample Solution (from a company, for a scientific camera), with projects inside it (c#, Visual Studio 2010). I tried to duplicate one of the projects so I could modify it by copying the project folder Foo, and renaming the project file to FooMod. I added the project to the solution. But when i modify the Form (add a button), it doesn't show up on the form when i run it. Also, i try to add a button to the original project Foo and now that doesn't work either.

I am able to add buttons to other projects in the solution just fine.

What am i missing? It seams I am not in fact modifying the form that is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that neither the Release or the Debug versions were getting built. Openning the Configuration Manager from the Shortcut list on the toolbar, the Build checkbox was unchecked for this project. Checking the Build box for Release and Debug results in the modified form running. The project is sdknetExample. The unchecked box is shown. I would still like to know why this box was unchecked.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution to the problem.  I'm sure you learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are building the debug version but running the (old, unchanged) release version.

Or vice-versa.

Comment: Sounds possible. How would i know or change it?

Comment: So I selected Release in the Solutions Configuration drop-down menu on the Toolbar. Then it runs the new edits. But in Debug, still doesn't.

Comment: There are two sub-directories deep under the project: Debug and Release.  Your builds will be found in those directories (usually).  If you build both versions, both should run.

Comment: Note to my comment above: when i built the Release version, i had also gone into the Configuration Manager (as in my posted answer) and checked the unchecked Build box.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the startup form: have you changed it in the file Program.cs?

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1()); // Put your new form here
    }
}
```

If it's not the startup form, make sure that all the references to the old form are changed to the new one.

Comment: To make sure that Form1 above referred to my new form, i changed name of form file in the Solution Explorer window. Got a message requesting to change all references in the project to this new name. Clicked Yes, and it updated the Form1 name in the Program.cs file. Still runs the old code.